# PHP simple equation

Tags: php

What's wrong with this? It's not working out

```
// define
$prv=0;

if(isset($_GET['prv'])) {
$prv = intval($_GET['prv']);
}

// security
if($prv != 0 OR $prv != 2)  {
die("<p>Error</p>");
}
```

This always goes through the `die()` part, even when `prv` is undefined or is defined as `2` in the url (`and is 2`)

And this does works:

```
// security
if($prv == 0 OR $prv == 2)  { } else {
die("<p>Error</p>");
}
```

Comment: you need an AND instead of OR

Comment: `X or Y` is true if either `X` is true or `Y` is true. So if `$prv` is 2 then `$prv != 0` is true, so the whole expression is true.

Comment: @user2386164, I think you can post that as an answer

Comment: Remember _deMorgan's Law_.

Comment: @Sergio meh, didn't feel like going into details. Thought someone would explain pretty quicly :P

Comment: Oh gosh, I always fail on this easy stuff. Thanks

Comment: Note, you should probably be using `&&` and `||` compared to `AND` and `OR`.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement to:

```
// security
if($prv != 0 AND $prv != 2)  {
    die("<p>Error</p>");
}
```

With the `OR` it will always evaluate as true because when $prv == 0 it does not equal 2. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the value of "prv" is, it certainly cannot be both 0 and 2 at the same time, so one of the conditions is always true; that's why you get in that clause.

Answer (score 0):

Break it down:

- if `$prv` is not 0, the first condition passes and the OR succeeds
- otherwise, `$pev` must be 0. Therefore it must be "not 2", so the OR succeeds.

Try `&&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`==` replace `!=`

```
if($prv != 0 AND $prv != 2)  {
    die("<p>Error</p>");
}
```